# Problem using macro with TikZ foreach

Tags: loops, pgffor

I am using a simple macro adapted from an answer to the following SO question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951392/latex-space-after-every-letter

The modified macro simply takes a string and adds a newline after each letter...

It works fine until I try to use it with a TikZ foreach loop at which point instead of returning the string with a char per line it returns the string...

Any thoughts on how or if the issue can be resolved?

The LaTeX is:

```
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\charperline}[1]{%                                                                                                           
  \@tfor\letter:=#1\do{%                                                                                                                 
    \letter\\%                                                                                                                           
  }%                                                                                                                                     
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\charperline{This Works}
\foreach \tmp in {Not This,Or This} {
  \charperline{\tmp}
}
\end{document}
```

And the following is the result from pdflatex:

[image]

There is nothing noteworthy in the log file.

**EDIT**

Just adding a slightly simpler version...

```
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\foreach \tmp in {Not This,Or This} {
  \@tfor\letter:=\tmp\do{%                                                                                                               
      \letter\\%                                                                                                                         
  }%                                                                                                                                     
}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to force `\tmp` to be expanded as a sequence of letters whereas at the moment `\charperline` is seeing it only as a single token. I am sure that there is an approved way of doing this but here is a way that I have used to get around similar problems in the past:

**Edit** As percusse says in the comments, a better solution is to use:

```
\foreach \tmp in {Not This,Or This} {
   \expandafter\charperline\expandafter{\tmp}
}



\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\charperline}[1]{%
  \@tfor\letter:=#1\do{%
    \letter\\%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\charperline{This Works}
\foreach \tmp in {Not This,Or This} {
   \edef\Charpy{\noexpand\charperline{\tmp}}
   \Charpy
}
\end{document}
```

The `\edef` forces `\tmp` to expand so that `\Charpy` is defined to be `\charperline{Not This}` (when `\tmp` is "Not This"), and then `\Charpy` applies `\charperline` to "Not This" as you want it to:

[image]

Comment: `\expandafter\charperline\expandafter{\tmp}` should also work.

Comment: @percusse  I am confused because, for me, `\expandafter\charperline\expandafter{\tmp}` does not work?? If instead I try `\expandafter\charperline\expandafter\tmp` it is a little better in that the "N" from "Not this" is on its' own line, but not the rest... (I am nervous however as whenever I "correct" egreg I am invariably wrong and you understand this much better than I do:)

Comment: I'm definitely not in that league but it works when I replace the body of the foreach loop with that one liner. So it becomes `\foreach\tmp in{Not This,Or This}{\expandafter\charperline\expandafter{\tmp}}`.

Comment: Thanks guys! Both of the solutions worked for me. I had tried \expandafter but clearly don't understand it fully because I tried to use a single \expandafter before \charperline{\tmp} with no effect. And I've learned something new with the use of \edef and \noexpand. Thanks!!

Comment: @percusse Yep, it was me: I missed the second `\expandafter`... :( This is a much better solution than mine.